# Sharepoint Webparts

Tags: sharepoint-2007

When ever I deploy a webpart and try to browse it, It comes up with the following error on the site:

Go back to site
Error

"Cannot complete this action.

Please try again. 
Troubleshoot issues with Windows SharePoint Services. "

when I go back and open the site the problem gets fixed.

could anybody point me what cause this error?

Thank you.
Hari

Comment: please don't edit replies into other peoples answers

Comment: where do I post the reply then,, You don't need to mark me down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to try would be to turn off custom errors in SharePoint, to do this follow these steps:

- Navigate to your web.config file (i.e. c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectoriesa\80)
- Make a backup of your web.config file
- Open your live web.config file
- Chnge the 'SafeMode' tag so that **CallStack="false"** is set to **CallStack="true"** and **AllowPageLevelTrace="false"** is set to **AllowPageLevelTrace="true"**
- Change the line **customErrors mode="On"** to **customErrors mode="Off"**
- Save and close the web.config file

Now you have done that, you should be able to see the ASP.NET error instead of the sharepoint generic errors.  This should give you some more information on the error to allow you to pin point the problem easier.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are in a farm environment if might have something to do with the web.configs getting updated.
2. Or it might be that your web part properties are inconsistent, and the first load fails, but corrects the data, and then the web part is okay.

Comment: How can I make my web part properties consistent?